# UTF-8 JsonObjectRequest support in Volley

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I have an utf-8 json file.

How can I print it with utf-8 support?

```
output = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.jData);
    JsonObjectRequest jor = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, loginURL, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {


                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    try{

                        JSONArray ja = response.getJSONArray("posts");


                        for(int i=0; i < ja.length(); i++){

                            JSONObject jsonObject = ja.getJSONObject(i);


                            String title = jsonObject.getString("title");
                            String text = jsonObject.getString("text");

                            data += "Blog Number "+(i+1)+" \n title= "+title  +" \n text= "+ text +" \n\n\n\n ";

                        }

                        output.setText(data);
                    }catch(JSONException e){e.printStackTrace();}
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e("Volley","Error");

                }
            }
    );
    requestQueue.add(jor);
```

The data (json file) were created by myself and I saved them with  UTF-8 encoding:

```
{
    "found": 2,
    "posts": [{
        "title": "title",
        "text": "text"
    },  {
        "title": "title",
        "text": "text"
    }]
}
```

I changed Android File Encoding Settings on UTF-8, but nothing changed. How fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by overriding the `parseNetworkResponse` method of the JsonObjectRequest class.  First make a new class which extends JsonObjectRequest:

```
public class Utf8JsonObjectRequest extends JsonObjectRequest {

    public Utf8JsonObjectRequest(int method, 
                                 String url, 
                                 Response.Listener<JSONObject> listener, 
                                 Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {

        super(method, url, listener, errorListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected Response<T> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {

        try {
                String json = new String(
                    response.data,
                    "UTF-8"
            );

            return Response.success(
                    new JSONObject(json),
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response)

            );

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        }
    }
}
```

Then use your new class in place of JsonObjectRequest:

```
Utf8JsonObjectRequest jor = new Utf8JsonObjectRequest(
    Request.Method.GET, 
    loginURL, 
    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

           //...     
        }
    },
    new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("Volley","Error");

        }
    }     
);
```

Comment: can u please give more info? I am new in android and I could't use this code. (my orginal code is in a onCreateView() in a fragment class.